# Returning a shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I have a function that needs to return a new object of another class, so I think I need to hold its return object in a shared pointer. Like this

Inside class X;

```
Y* func(param)
{
   return new Y(param);
}
```

I've tried changing it into

```
std::shared_ptr<Y> func(param)
{
   std::shared_ptr<Y> y(new Y(param));
   return y;
}
```

I don't want to return a local object, so what should I do ?

Comment: You aren't returning a local object, you're returning a copy. Also it's `std::shared_ptr`. Use `std::make_shared`.

Comment: After changing `share_ptr` to `shared_ptr`, it should work.

Comment: In neither case do you return a local object, in both cases the returned value is *copied*. In the first the pointer is copies, and in the second the object is copied. Also, and perhaps unrelated, but you should not look at `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` as *pointers*, instead most of the time you should look at them from an *ownership* perspective.

Comment: In truth, you're not returning *anything*, because this won't even *compile*. `std::shared_ptr<Y> func(param)` isn't even valid C++. But props for at least considering smart pointers. its more than many would do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend that you have `std::shared_ptr` as return type and `return std::make_shared<Y>()` to transfer ownership.
Here is a working example that might help you:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Y {
public:
    Y(const std::string& n)
    : name{n} {}

    std::string name;
};

std::shared_ptr<Y> func()
{
    return std::make_shared<Y>("new class");
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Y> p_class = func();
    std::cout << p_class->name;
    // outputs: "new class"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You return a heap-allocated object which means you transfer ownership. I would suggest you use `std::unique_ptr` as the return type

```
std::unique_ptr<Y> func(param)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<Y>(new Y(param));
}
```

Even better is to use std::make_unique (if it is already available, otherwise write your own) or - if you use shared_ptr - std::make_shared. It is better for exception safety and in case of shared_ptr more efficient.

```
std::unique_ptr<Y> func(param)
{
   return make_unique<Y>(param);
}

std::shared_ptr<Y> func(param)
{
   return std::shared_ptr<Y>(param);
}
```

And be aware that your `func` copied the parameter. You may want to use forwarding to avoid this.

```
template<class T, class U>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique1(U&& u)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(u)));
}

template<class T, class... U>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(U&&... u)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(u)...));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my answer suggesting `std::unique_ptr`, I want to point out that it is not necessary to create an object on the heap to return it from a function. You can just return the new object by value:

```
Y func(param)
{
   Y result(param);
   return result;
}
```

This will (and has always) worked if `Y` is copyable. It will not work if the class is not copyable, and if it works, it may involve copying the object.

While most compilers did eliminate the copy for years, this is now mandatory by the standard `C++17` if you return an unnamed temporary object. That means that the following code will compile and return a new object even if you have a non-copyable and non-movable object:

```
class Y {
  public:
  Y(int i): value(i) {}
  Y(Y const&) = delete;
  Y(Y&&) = delete;
  Y& operator=(Y const&) = delete;
  Y& operator=(Y&&) = delete;

  int value;
};

Y foo(int i) {
  return Y(i);
}

void bar {
  Y y = foo(42);
}
```